# When navigation drawer gets populated with items?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, navigation-drawer

Need a little clarification. I create drawer in accordance with docs:

```
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
adapter = new NavDrawerAdapter(this);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Later I want to get the first item of the list like that:

```
View view = mDrawerList.getChildAt(0);
```

`view` happens to be `null` in onCreate() and even in onPostCreate(). What's the point? When the adapter populates the `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `adapter.getItem` instead of `mDrawerList.getChildAt` and make sure you have insert the items to the `ListView` (`adapter.add`)

Answer (score 1):

With `ListView` you should use `OnItemClickListener`. The `onItemClick` gets the `position` of the clicked item and the an `AdapterView`'s object. On the latter you can call

```
 adapterViewInstance.getItemAtPosition(position)
```